# HttpWebRequest failed: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL\/TLS secure channel

Tags: .net, web-services, httpwebrequest, tls1.2

I have searched all over the web but could not find a proper working solution. So I am going to ask for my case specifically again.

The original application is coded in .Net 4.0 and has no problem to calling the web service. After some version upgrade of the remote system, I am getting error:
**The request was aborted: could not create SSL/TLS secure channel**
at line 4 below, after some googling, I found it is because missing TLS 1.2 support in the original .Net 4.0 application.

The changes I made was recomplie the solution to .Net 4.7.2 and added code line 1. But a new error appears: **The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.**

A workaround solution suggested adding line 2 to ignore the certificate validation, but that seems  causing a security hole. And I read one of the answer here mentioned about certificate. But I am not sure what exactly need to be done. If there is any certificate required, it should have already set up before, unless something new requires a new certificate?

```
 //  Adding TLS12 support
 1.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
 2.//ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

 3.HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(mRestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
 4.using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)   
 {   
 5.   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());   
 6.   mReturn =  reader.ReadToEnd();   
 }
```